# Load Images into diffrent movie clips using the same function

Tags: actionscript-3

So I got 5 different movie clips on my stage and I'm trying to load images into them by using their names.
here is what I got (still nothing). can you point me to the right direction please?

```
  function imgLoader(im2load:String,place2put:String) {
    var req:URLRequest=new URLRequest(im2load);
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();

    function fileLoaded(event:Event):void {
        BGPut(loader,place2put);
    }

    function preload(event:ProgressEvent):void {
        var percent:Number=Math.round(event.bytesLoaded/event.bytesTotal*100);
        inf_txt.text=String(percent)+"%";
    }

    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileLoaded);
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, preload);
    loader.load(req);
}

function BGPut(put,place):void {

    while (????.numChildren>1) {
        ???.removeChildAt(0)
    }
    ???.addChild(put);  
}

imgLoader("bg/bg1.jpg","BGHold");
```

and if you have any suggestion on loading them in a sequence shoot ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the movie clip that contains your 5 movie clips:

```
var m0: MovieClip = this.getChildByName(place) as MovieClip;
while (m0.numChildren>1)
{
    m0.removeChildAt(0);
}
m0.addChild(put);
```